Why is my MailMerge Toolkit Add-in not sending emails at the very last step?
'The RPC server is unavailable.' --------------------------- 'Error: "The RPC server is unavailable." Description: "Call of [OnResolveNameBefore] failed: 'The RPC server is unavailable.'" "MAPILab.MMTAddin" File: UtilsCOM.cpp Line: 95 Method: Utils::COM::GetDispErrorDescription'
Please help me troubleshoot this error. What should I do?
I changed the registry value to 3, so the MailMerge Toolkit is active as an add-in in both Old Outlook and Word. I also made sure to make old Outlook the default program for all kinds of functions.

This does not sound like a programming question. Please contact the addin vendor.

Okay, thank you
